# Anyone have a Taser recording?

Tags: request, sound-effects, trade

I'm working on a pro-bono project for a friend and I need some Taser sounds tonight. Anywhere I could buy one right now is closed. I'm foreseeing it might be a little difficult to synthesize them and normally I'd be up for that challenge but there's not much time to experiment.

Anyone have any recordings I can use or anyone able to record some quick taser zaps for me? I'd be willing to trade or return the favor. Mono, 48/24 wav is workable.

Or if you have any suggestions on how to create the sound I'm all ears.

Thanks in advance!!!

**Update:**

In the wait for replies I think I sort of answered my own question and came up with a quick solution. I took a recording I have of a Roland TR-808's trigger output (used for sync with other old school analog synths), Sequenced 3 seconds worth of it at 1/16 in a 200BPM session, EQ'd it, and bussed it to two Aux tracks. One with a filter and distortion,and another with a different filter and different distortion with a bit of bit-reduction/decimation and severely limited and smashed the master output. [Here is the result as a 3 second loop](http://files.me.com/synsynth/hcprq7.wav)

If my memory is serving me correctly (it's been about 11 years since I last heard a Taser in person), it's pretty close approximation.

You guys can feel free to use it however you like. This sound is attributed a [WTFPL - Do What The Fv(|< You Want To Public License](http://sam.zoy.org/wtfpl/)

Answer (score 1):

I've got a stun gun type taser recording made in the booth, so it sounds pretty dry but can be verbed out to whatever space you need.  ping me and I"ll hook you up.

Comment: @Rene - Awesome, I'd love to get it. Now I'm wondering how my custom creation stands up to the real thing. It's been a long time since I heard one in person and I just created mine from memory. You can email it to james[dot]kojac[at]gmail.com

Comment: sent to you this am.  let me know if you didn't get it.  rene[at]dallasaudiopost[dot]com

Answer (score 0):

I was working with Soundsnap a while back and saw a few go by:

http://www.soundsnap.com/search/audio/taser/score

That is if you're interested in buying the sound outright instead of building it yourself.

They're from the Blastwave library, so they may be designed... i.e. not really a taser but built from elements, but they sound about right.

Comment: If it's Blastwave, it's usually the real thing.

Comment: @Airborne - Yeah, I'm familiar with all the sample search sites. Not a situation where I can pay for anything since what I'm doing is a favor. Thanks though!

*I do have to say that I thought anything posted to soundsnap was free (within the monthly download limits). My ignorance and typical lack of searching for alternate resources besides recording/making sounds myself is a bit weak.

Answer (score 0):

Found only one on [freesound.org](http://www.freesound.org/samplesViewSingle.php?id=87321).  It's not bad.  You could probably build one by chopping up some electrical SFX you might already have.

Comment: Yeah, if my memory serves me correctly, that one is a little weak. Thank you though!